# Iterate tables from table id from href links until no table with specific table id is found

Tags: python, recursion, web-scraping, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am doing web scraping to the next web page (which is my root URL to start scraping tables): https://www.iso.org/standards-catalogue/browse-by-ics.html

What I am trying to achieve is to parse the table with id 'datatable-ics' and then from the 'ICS' links contained in href tags from td in each row make a new request to that link to scrape children table with id 'datatable-ics-children', which has the exact same structure than the parent. Moreover, I want to do this as many times as there are children tables with id 'datatable-ics-children'. Finally I am merging the tables as one pandas DataFrame.

I am using latest version of Python3 with Pandas and BS4. I have tried to build a recursive algorithm like a BST, but it is time and resources expensive.

This is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import requests

BASE_URL = 'https://www.iso.org'
ICS_MAIN_TABLE_ID = 'datatable-ics'
ICS_CHILDREN_TABLE_ID = 'datatable-ics-children'

def create_ics_json(p_url):
    merged_ics_df = pandas.concat(parse_ics_table(p_url, ICS_MAIN_TABLE_ID, []))
    print(merged_ics_df)
    merged_ics_df.to_json("ics.json", orient="records")

def parse_ics_table(p_url, p_table_id, p_ics_dfs):
    print('URL: ', p_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(p_url).text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table', id=p_table_id)
    if table is not None:
        df, links = read_ics_table(table)
        p_ics_dfs.append(df)
        iterate_children_links(p_ics_dfs, links)
    return p_ics_dfs

def iterate_children_links(p_ics_dfs, p_links):
    for link in p_links:
        if '' != link:
            try:
                pandas.concat(parse_ics_table(link, ICS_CHILDREN_TABLE_ID, p_ics_dfs))
            except ValueError:
                pass
            
def read_ics_table(p_table):
    df = pandas.read_html(str(p_table), converters={'ICS': str, 'Field': str})[0]
    links = []
    for tr in p_table.findAll("tr"):
        tds = tr.findAll("td", {"data-title":"ICS"})
        for each in tds:
            try:
                link = BASE_URL + each.find('a')['href']
            except TypeError:
                link = '' 
                continue
            finally:
               links.append(link) 
    df['Link'] = links
    return df, links
     
def main(url):
    create_ics_json(url)
```

Note that not always the column 'ICS' value contains a link and for those cases I am setting empty link ('').

Is it possible to refactor this and how?

Thank you in advance.